# How to use DISTINCT in VIEWS correctly

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, select, view, distinct

I have two tables from which I want to make a join with some columns to provide a view for my java/hibernate application. It looks like this:

```
CREATE VIEW customer_contacts AS cc
SELECT DISTINCT ON (cust.id) cust.id
  cust.company
  cust.zip
  ...
  con.name
  con.forename
  ...
FROM contacts con
LEFT JOIN customer cust ON con.customer = cust.id
ORDER BY cust.id
```

So far so good. Very simple. 
If I make a SELECT on the view like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cc
WHERE name ilike '%schult%'
```

I get **13 results**.

If I make the same query directly with the view statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (cust.id) cust.id
  cust.company
  cust.zip
  ...
  con.name
  con.forename
  ...
FROM contacts con
LEFT JOIN customer cust ON con.customer = cust.id
WHERE name ilike '%schult%'
ORDER BY cust.id
```

I got **75 results**!
I figured out that it is the DISTINCT that corrupts the result. But why?

And how can I use it correctly?

Comment: Please show the exact SQL text of the "same query" that you are running.

Comment: Hi Peter, I clarified my question and I have written the direct statement.

Comment: But you forgot the condition `WHERE name ilike '%schult%'` in your second query...

Comment: Right you are! But now

Answer (score 1):

Your queries (view based and direct) have different order of applying condition:

- direct query searches for `%shult%` and then applies `distinct on`
- view applies `distinct on` and then searches for `%shult%`

Are you aware how `distinct on` works?
It selects first row (it may be undeterministic if proper sort is not defined) for given attributes and leaves other.

For instance:

Let's say we have customer with `id=1` and two connected contacts one with `name='Schultz'` and one with `name='Schmidt'`.
Now view based select will apply `distinct on` and select customer with some contact (first one, undeterministic in this case), then `name ilike '%schult%'` will be applied - it may happen that Schultz will be removed by `distinct on`.

---

Recommended reading:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Comment: Thanks. Your first point is clear and I found it in the postgre Doc. The second one not. But my question remains: How can I do it correctly. I mean, how do I get the result I want maybe without the view? I am using Hibernate and don't want to use a query. That's why I am wanted to use a view.

Comment: And by the way. The result in this very special case will be the same because there are no duplicates. So the order shouldn't matter. In other queries it is possible.

Comment: I don't get it: " there are no duplicates". If there were no duplicates both your queries would return the same data.

Comment: Well in this case, when I add this "where-clause (where name ilike '%schulte%' " there are **different** results and that is exactly the problem. The two queries return different results! But when I try for example  "where city ilike '%Berlin%') the results are the same!